# Percentage CSS not accurate

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with the code:

```css
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300&subset=latin,latin-ext);
 body {
   background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
   background-size: 100% auto;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .header {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   height: 10%;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
   top: 0;
 }
 .content {
   position: fixed;
   height: 84%;
   width: 100%;
   top: 10%;
   padding: 2%;
 }
 .footer {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 2;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 6%;
   background-color: #263238;
 }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section class="container">

    <section class="header"></section>



    <section class="content">

      <div class="index_news">
        aaa
      </div>

      <div class="index_top">
        ccc
      </div>

    </section>

    <section class="footer"></section>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Section with CONTENT class should be accurately between HEADER and the FOOTER, but on the page it is bigger then it should be. Do You know why?

Comment: add this `*{box-sizing:border-box;}` so that `padding/border` is taken from inside

Comment: because You use `padding:2%`

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Side note; you can use `<header/>` and `<footer/>` tags. From SEO perspective that's better then using `<section/>`'s, which are meant primarily for different sections in the site's content. And don't use a section for a wrapper. As a wrapper is nothing more then technical, an oldschool `<div/>` is better suited for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `border-box` value for the box sizing, in this way the padding will not affect the outer width, instead it will be relative to the border. Besides, your footer is positioned `fixed` to the bottom, this make the illusion that the content does not fit in the middle, but your content div size is proper if you remove the `height: 84%;`, otherwise it will be taking 84% of the containers height.

```
.content {
       position: fixed;
       height: 84%;
       width: 100%;
       top: 10%;
       padding: 2%;



      /*  box sizing - brower compatible   */
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
     }
```

Code snippet :

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300&subset=latin,latin-ext);
 body {
   background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
   background-size: 100% auto;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .header {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   height: 10%;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
   top: 0;
 }
 .content {
   position: fixed;
   height: 84%;
   width: 100%;
   top: 10%;
   padding: 2%;
   


  /*  use the border box for the box sizing, in this way the padding will not affect the outer width, instead it will be relative to the border    */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .footer {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 2;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 6%;
   background-color: #263238;
 }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section class="container">

    <section class="header"></section>



    <section class="content">

      <div class="index_news">
        aaa
      </div>

      <div class="index_top">
        ccc
      </div>

    </section>

    <section class="footer"></section>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`width` is 100% and `padding` is 2%. So total width of the content div is 104%.

Changing width to 96% will fix it.

Below is the updated css.

```
.content {
    position: fixed;
    height: 84%;
    width: 96%;
    top: 10%;
    padding: 2%;
}
```